# Undefined notation in Causality book

Tags: probability, bayesian

I'm reading the book Causality - Models, Reasoning and Inference (Second edition).

On page 11 the Decomposition property uses the notation $YW$, which is not defined before. What does $YW$ mean, please?

Comment: See [Rules of conditional independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence#Rules_of_conditional_independence) : it seems taht Pearl juxtaposes the random variables $YW$ instead of writing $Y,W$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks a lot!